# Check that variable is a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check that a variable is a number, either an integer or a string digit?

In PHP I could do:

```
if (is_int($var)) {
    echo '$var is integer';
}
```

Or:

```
if (is_numeric($var)) {
    echo '$var is numeric';
}
```

How can I do it in jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are trying to avoid a round-trip to your server to test?  That would be the brain-dead-easy way ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'd go with

```
isFinite(String(foo))
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600763/checking-if-a-variable-contains-a-numerical-value-in-javascript/601877#601877) for an explanation why. If you only want to accept integer values, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323314/detecting-if-a-given-number-is-an-integer/1323325#1323325).

Comment: Watch out for this. `isFinite(null) === true`

Comment: isFinite("100") is true, we want to know that an object is a Number object. From my brief testing it looks like the solution here (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Number]") is the best: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript

Comment: Also returns true with an empty string, which I wouldn't consider a "number"

Comment: Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Number]" will return true if passing NaN

Comment: Does not handle all variables: `isFinite(String(" ")) == isFinite(String("\t")) == isFinite(String("")) == true`. See the answer linked.

Comment: I think `Number.isFinite()` is what you want. Behaves correctly with `null` and `''`

Answer (score 45):

The javascript function `isNaN(variable)` should do the trick. It returns true if the data is not a number.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. FWIW, this works because strings are implicitly converted to numbers - the explicit code is: `isNaN(new Number(variable))`. Note that if you wish to restrict the code to integers, `parseInt()` will return `NaN` (testable via `isNaN()`). Be aware though that `parseInt()` will happily ignore non-numberic digits at the end of the string.

Comment: this will accept everything which can be converted to a number, including boolean values and `'infinity'`; better use `isFinite(String(foo))`

Comment: Don't use isNaN, it's broken. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN and use the solution proposed by @Christoph instead.

Answer (score 13):

I'm pretty new to javascript but it seems like `typeof(blah)` lets you check if something is a number (it doesn't say true for strings).  A know the OP asked for strings + numbers but I thought this might be worth documenting for other people.

eg:

```
function isNumeric(something){
    return typeof(something) === 'number';
}
```

Here are [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

and here's a few console runs of what typeof produces:

```
typeof(12);
"number"
typeof(null);
"object"
typeof('12');
"string"
typeof(12.3225);
"number"
```

one slight weirdness I am aware of is

```
typeof(NaN);
"number"
```

but it wouldn't be javascript without something like that right?!

Comment: It's better JS style to use `typeof(something) == 'number'`. With `==` rather than `===`. Reserve `===` for when you really mean it.

Comment: @AdamChalcraft most linters/programmers would probably disagree and say the opposite - always use `===` unless there's a good reason not to, if you'll get into the habit of using `==` you'll get burned by something bizaare happening at some point. In this case there's no type coercion going on so it's a fairly moot point either way.  For an educational (and also hilarious) rant on the topic check out James Mickens' "To wash it all away" http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/mickens/files/towashitallaway.pdf

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
if(Number.isInteger(variable))
   alert("It is an integer");
else
   alert("It is not a integer");
```

you can find the reference in:
[Number.isInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNumeric( $probe )
{
    return parseFloat( String( $probe ) ) == $probe;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
var x = 23;
var y = 34hhj;

isNaN(x); 
isNaN(y);
```

It will return true if its string and false if its a number.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

simple way to check whether given value is number by using "if condition"

```
function isInteger(value)      
{       
    num=value.trim();         
    return !(value.match(/\s/g)||num==""||isNaN(num)||(typeof(value)=='number');        
}
```

it  will return true if the value which we are passing is an integer..

```
solved for     
value=""      //false null     
value="12"    //true only integers       
value="a"     //false     
value=" 12"   //false      
value="12 "   //false         
value=" "     //false space        
value="$12"   //false special characters 
value="as12"    //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that empty string `''` and `' '` will be considered as number by `isNaN` and `isFinite`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:  `$.isNumeric( i )`

[jQuery.isNumeric API](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)

Answer (score 0):

The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

```js
const num = 42;
console.log(typeof num === "number"); // expected return true
if(typeof num === "number"){
   console.log("This is number")
}
```

### More on it......

```js
console.log(typeof 42);
// expected output: "number"

console.log(typeof 'blubber');
// expected output: "string"

console.log(typeof true);
// expected output: "boolean"

console.log(typeof undeclaredVariable);
// expected output: "undefined"
```