# redirect knockout js observable if containing string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a input field in my  html which basically sends the amount to an observable and then redirects to different pages depending on the amount, but I want to make sure that even if a person who doesnt write amount and types in "string values" should still be able to get redirected, but I am not sure how to accomplish that.

**HTML CODE**

```
<input id="amount"  type="text" data-bind="value : amount" />
<button class="btn button2" type="submit"  data-bind=" valueUpdate:'afterkeydown' , click: $root.borrow_first_pageview" ></button>
```

I do not want to write the type= number in the HTML since I want to know how its checked in the JS.

here is the rest code using knockout.js

```
self.borrow_first_pageview = function () {
        if(self.amount()){
            window.location.href = BASEURL + "index.php/moneyexchange/borrow_first_page/" + self.amount(); 
        }else if(typeof self.amount() == 'string'){
            window.location.href = BASEURL + "index.php/moneyexchange/borrow_first_page/" + 2500;
        }else {
             window.location.href = BASEURL + "index.php/moneyexchange/borrow_first_page/" + 2500;
        }

    };
```

Is there a way to check if self.amount() is a String and then redirect the user. Need help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a variable is a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string). (Though perhaps slightly masked by other details in the question, amongst one that `self.amount` is *not* executed to get its value in the `else if` condition. But a dupe most likely nonetheles...). Alternatively, it may be a dupe of [Check that variable is a number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1352577/419956)

Comment: So.. what you actually want to check is if the amount is a decimal/integer. You can use parseInt/parseFloat for that

Comment: @Magrangs no I want to check if someone puts a string instead of amount, since the function crashes if someone puts a string so I need to check it and then redirect them.

Comment: @MasnadNihit yeah so if it parses as a decimal/int you know its not a string

Comment: @Jeroen its not that much similar, since I tried typeOf but I am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: yea, so is there a way to check if self.amount() == parseFloat??  @Magrangs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we can reverse the problem and see if the amount is a number or not and then act accordingly:

```
var value = self.amount();
if((+value == value) && !isNaN(+value)){
    //Yey we have a valid number.
}
```

This is probably one of the few valid uses of a loose equality operator I have found (it guards against null and "" being passed in). It uses the unary plus operator plus a little bit of magic and it's a nice short way of checking if a value is a number or not.

You can put this into a function if you like, 'IsNumber' for example:

```
function isNumber(value){
    //loose equality operator used to guard against nulls, undefined and empty string
    return ((+value == value) && !isNaN(+value));
}
```

Comment: This works! thanks alot, I am not sure what +value and isNan(+value) means but it does work.

Comment: Ha, yeah, it's a little bit cryptic but it's concise. the + is called the unary plus which does a coercion on the value, try it in the console. isNaN checks the if the value is Not a Number. The loose equality operator == doesn't do a strict comparison (using types. e.g. +"2" == "2" is true but +"2blah" == "2" is false)  so that combined with isNaN check gives a way to check if a variety of numbers are actually numbers.