# Test if field value is numeric and not empty

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate that a string is a positive integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834796/validate-that-a-string-is-a-positive-integer)

So I want to check a form field if it's empty and to allow it to has only positive numeric numbers, no spaces or letters. So far I succeed the first part to check if the field is empty with the following code:

```
function validate(form) {
    var elements = form.elements;

    if (form.qty.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the field");
        document.forms[0].qty.focus()
        document.forms[0].qty.select()
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Somewhere in the form:

`<form action="addtocart.php" method ="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);" />` ...

But now I want to allow only numbers as well as to check if the field is empty. I have found some scripts but I don't know how to merge the code into one valid script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (Number(form.qty.value) > 0) {
    // Only executes if value is a positive number.
}
```

Note that if the value is an empty string the statement will not return true. The same goes for `null`, `NaN` (obviously) and `undefined`. String representations of numbers are transformed into their numeric counterparts.

Comment: This evaluates to `true` on floats, so unless OP is willing to chop up products for customers that want 1.5 qty...

Comment: @MrCode - He said "positive numeric numbers". Nowhere did he specify that he needed an integer. Perhaps he is selling something by weight, he didn't specify.

Comment: In any case, you could always add something like `number % 1 == 0;`

Comment: If that is what he wants. He is going to have to say so if that is the case, however.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [regexp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
your pattern is `^\d+$`.

`^` - starting of the line
`$` - end of the line
`\d` - digit
`+` - 1 or more times

```
if(mystr.match(/^\d+$/))
{
    //
}
```

if you need the first symbol not to be `0` you should write `/^(0|[^1-9]\d*)/`
read regexp documentation to understand this pattern.

Comment: Doesn't work for strings like: `"1e5"`, or for float values. (`"123,456" / "123.456"`)

Comment: aw... in that case other answers are better.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `search()` function and RegExp. Like this:

```
if (form.qty.value.search(/^([0-9\.]+)$/)==-1)
{
alert ("Please enter the field");
document.forms[0].qty.focus()
document.forms[0].qty.select()
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I'm more than new in js and this work as i wanted to!

Comment: Doesn't work for strings like: `"1e5"`, or for float values using a comma as separator. (`"123,456"`)

Comment: Nor works for invalid: "1.2.3"

Answer (score 0):

Check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10270826/783743

In your case I would do the following:

```
function validate(form) {
    return isPositive(+form.qty.value);
}

function isPositive(n) {
    return +n === n && n >= 0;
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. The expression `+form.qty.value` coerces the string to a number. If the string is empty or is not a number it will express `NaN`.
2. The function `isPositive` only returns positive if `n` is a number (`+n === n`) and it's greater than or equal to zero (`n >= 0`).

Comment: This does not appear to work for float values.
Also, I'd suggest explaining how your bitwise operations work (Like the `+` when passing the parameter.

Comment: @Cerbrus - The plus operator (`+`) is not a bitwise operator. It's used to coerce a primitive value (boolean, string or number) to a number. The function `isPositive` expects `n` to be a number. The expression `+n === n` only returns `true` if `n` is a number and it's not `NaN`.