# Bootstrap carousel - link to specific slide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have found a lot of help on displaying the current slide number in the html and linking to a particular slide on the current page but my question is a little different...

I need to be able to link to a particular slide in the carousel in another page. So I will have something like:  a href="page2.html#slide2"  on 'index.html'

When the user clicks this link, it takes them to the 'page2.html' page and with the second slide displayed.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You'll need to store the index of the slide in the url so for slide2 the index would be `1`.  Then when you load the page you need to grab the index from the url and then call `$('#myCarousel').carousel(index);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a query string like... www.example.com?slide=2

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    $('#myCarousel').carousel(getParameterByName('slide'));
});
```

Or hash values like... www.example.com#2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(window.location.hash.substring(1));
});
```

Which ever you use, you have to only extract an integer from the url, so you may want to make the code a little more robust to ensure you are only moving the carousel if you get a valid integer and also check that it is within the bounds of the number of slides that exist within the carousel.

**.carousel(number)**

Cycles the carousel to a particular frame **(0 based, similar to an array).**

Comment: what would you add to the carousel to achieve this?

Comment: Just a note that `carousel` expects an integer and `getParameterByName()` will always return a string.  This will cause problems so you should look into casting or using @cdonner's solution below.

Answer (score 4):

New and improved version tests for a valid integer and defaults to 0:

```
function qs(key) {
    key = key.replace(/[*+?^$.\[\]{}()|\\\/]/g, "\\$&"); // escape RegEx meta chars
    var match = location.search.match(new RegExp("[?&]" + key + "=([^&]+)(&|$)"));
    var slide = match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    if (Math.floor(slide) == slide && $.isNumeric(slide))
        return parseInt(slide);
    else
        return 0;
}
$('#myCarousel').carousel(qs('slide'));
```

Credits go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270648/determine-if-javascript-value-is-an-integer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731778/jquery-get-query-string-parameters) question.

Comment: Is there a way to update the url when the slide changes by using the carousel controls? For example, to go from www.webpage.com?=slide1 to www.webpage.com?=slide2 ?