# Start From Specific Slide in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I've read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249841/bootstrap-carousel-link-to-specific-slide), but I'm still having trouble implementing the code. I've copied that javascript exactly into my custom.js file, and it said my HTML code wouldn't need to be modified. However, it still isn't working. What do I need to change?

Relevant portions of HTML file:

```
<!-- Nav bar -->

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="project1.html?slide=0">Project 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="project1.html?slide=1">Project 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="project1.html?slide=2">Project 3</a></li>
</ul>



<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/Project1.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Project 1</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/Project2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Project 2</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/Project3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Project 3</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
<!-- /.carousel -->
```

I notice that the second slide has an active class, but removing that just breaks the carousel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to manually set the active class in HTML, you just need to add the `active` class to the following elements:

- `<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>`
- `<div class="item active"> <!-- for slide 2 -->`

As in this demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/300?image=1" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Project 1</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/300?image=3" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Project 2</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/300?image=4" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Project 3</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

However, doing so will not persist across page refreshes.  Or at least certainly won't do so in a dynamic way.  If you're going to load the active slide with Javascript, then you don't need to fuss around with manually setting the `active` class.  Just call the `.carousel(index)` with the zero based index of the side you want to navigate to like this:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel(1);
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(1);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/300?image=1" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Project 1</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/300?image=3" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Project 2</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/300?image=4" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Project 3</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The million dollar question is how can you get the javascript above to run on page load.

The answer to that depends on how you're configuring your links and your site.  For this particular case, you need to pass `carousel` an integer and the search property always returns a string, even if it's a numeric set of digits.  Therefore, you should use the [new and improved answer to your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913377/1366033):

```
$(function(){

    function getParameterByName(key) {
      key = key.replace(/[*+?^$.\[\]{}()|\\\/]/g, "\\$&"); // escape RegEx meta chars
      var match = location.search.match(new RegExp("[?&]" + key + "=([^&]+)(&|$)"));
      var slide = match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
      if (Math.floor(slide) == slide && $.isNumeric(slide))
          return parseInt(slide);
      else
          return 0;
    }

    var slideNumber = getParameterByName('slide');

    $('#myCarousel').carousel(slideNumber);
});
```

Assuming your are going to pass in a query string like `?slide=` then that information should be available in the `window.location.search` property.

Neither StackSnippets or jsFiddle seem to pass the `location.search`. But here's a plunker that demontrates this working:

#### [Working Demo in Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/WeBsDkRLFop0oY3wHwQY)

Which you can see working at this address:

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/WeBsDkRLFop0oY3wHwQY/index.html?slide=1

Answer (score -2):

need to say I'm a newbie in this, and I'm using Mobirise as a support.
That being said, what I haven't found (or haven't understood) in your answers is how to create a link to open a specific slide, user end, maybe adding something at the end of the url? I created a bootstrap carousel sample with mobirise for you to check out.
[gallery link](http://www.sbirigula.com/gallery.rar)

Comment: Don't use external resources if not necessary. You should be able to add the relevant "answering" code to this question. Other people visiting this site is most likely unwilling to download and extract a random RAR file from some unknown user on stackoverflow.

Comment: Good point. :P Problem is I don't really know which one is the code I should post for this.

Comment: Well, I would suggest that you either do now or you wait with trying to answer. If you care about your rep, you can remove your answers that have received negative votes or improve your answer so that people up vote it instead.