# Bookmark Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Assume that there are five items in the carousel and I like to add a html bookmark to the 2nd item of bootstrap carousel. I know how a bookmark works in different pages but I don't know how to capture carousel item through URL.

Comment: What did you try so far? Any piece of code to show?

Comment: @JeremyThille I just have bootstrap generic carousel code, I don't have anything to show other than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For eg. if your URL reads `http://example.com#2` then with the help of below given JS I will be landed to 3rd slide of the carousel.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slideNumber = parseInt(window.location.hash.substring(1));
  $('#carousel-slide').carousel(slideNumber);
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what @JeremyThille and me were talking about in the comments of the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is in de **[Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-methods)**

> .carousel(number)
>
> Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based, similar to an
>   array).

Create a javascript function:

```
function goToSlide(number) {
   $("#carousel").carousel(number);
}
```

And then, just add an `onClick` event on your link.

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:goToSlide(2);">Go to slide #2</a>
```

Comment: You mean create a bookmark to your favorites stored in a web browser?

Comment: Use the URL hash. For instance, add #3 to your URL. When you bookmark this, the #3 will be saved along with the URL. Then, in your code, read the hash (`window.location.hash`) at load time and go to the corresponding slide using equisde's function.

Comment: @JeremyThille gave a good advice. You have an example [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249841/bootstrap-carousel-link-to-specific-slide) on how to read the hash.

Comment: @equisde your solution has it's own advantage but doesn't serve my purpose. Thanks for helping :) I have posted answer to my question, you can have a look.