# Bootrap 3 carousel slide control by link of another page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

> THe services page http://testingatenspree.com/elusmock2/service.html has 6 services and it should go to specific service to the slider.
>   I tried anchor tag jump and added slider section with an id. so that on click of specific service that service of the slid should appear first

Comment: Have done it

Thanks to link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539058/linking-to-a-certain-bootstrap-carousel-slide-from-another-page

Answer (score 0):

You can use the carousal index to set on page load which you can pass in anchor tag URL as query string like

```
<a class="services-ttl-anch" href="all-services.html?slide=2"></a>
```

and then in all-services page you need to get the query string "slide" value in load the slide with index like below:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel(parseInt(getParameterByName('slide',window.location.href)));
```

To get query string value use below code:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
results = regex.exec(url);
if (!results) return null;
if (!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

}