# Carousel - linking to slide from another page - why Url Hash Navigation not working?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, owl-carousel

Can't get the link with the #tag to be recognised.

The items `data-hash` shows up in the browser URL window, but isn't being recognised by the script.

I'm using the standard script on the carousel page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.sidetext-carousel').owlCarousel({
            items: 1, 
            loop: false, 
            center:true, 
            margin:30, 
            URLhashListener:true,
            startPosition: 'URLHash',
            });
        })
```

is this being overiden by other JS, such as this, which is in the owl.carousel_main.js file?

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    var fullHeight = function() {
        $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
        });
    };
    fullHeight();

var carousel = function() {
    $('.sidetext-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        autoplay: false,
        margin:30,
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        animateIn: 'fadeIn', 
        nav:true,
        dots: true,
        autoplayHoverPause: false,
        items: 1,
        navText : ["<p><small></small><span class='ion-ios-arrow-round-back'></span></p>","<p><small></small><span class='ion-ios-arrow-round-forward'></span></p>"],
        responsive:{
          0:{
            items:1
          },
          600:{
            items:1
          },
          1000:{
            items:1
          }
    }
    });
};
carousel();
```

})(jQuery);

Or is there a way to give the UrLHashNavigation script priority?

Or have I got the script in the wrong place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this being overiden by other JS, such as this, which is in the owl.carousel_main.js file?

No, because you can only call the Owl initializer function once. First come first serve. You will need to combine the two setup scripts with all the carousel options (items:1, loop:false, etc) in a single call.

Because your first Owl initializer script is placed **before** you included jQuery and the carousel JavaScript, it will fail and be ignored. But since your `..._main.js` is included in the proper order, it runs.

**To fix**

Combine the two scripts, for example:

```
$('.sidetext-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1, 
  loop: false, 
  center: true, 
  margin: 30, 
  URLhashListener: true,
  startPosition: 'URLHash',
  autoplay: false, 
  animateOut: 'fadeOut',
  animateIn: 'fadeIn', 
  nav: true,
  dots: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: false,
  navText : ["<p><small></small><span class='ion-ios-arrow-round-back'></span></p>","<p><small></small><span class='ion-ios-arrow-round-forward'></span></p>"],
  responsive:{
    0:{
      items:1
    },
    600:{
      items:1
    },
    1000:{
      items:1
    }
}
```

Note I did not validate the options, I copied them from you. If it had an error, it's still there.

Then remove the first initializer script and include the combined initializer script  (assuming you put it in the `..._main.js`) **after** including jQuery and the Owl.js: :

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel_main.js"></script>
```

And things should work.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Worked first time ! You've made my weekend !