# Number.isInteger(x) which is created can not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, numbers, isinteger

```js
Number.prototype.isInteger = Number.prototype.isInteger || function(x) {
  return (x ^ 0) === x;
}
console.log(Number.isInteger(1));
```

will throw error in IE10 browser

Comment: can you post the error

Answer (score 9):

Apparently, IE treats DOM objects and Javascript objects separately, and you can't extend the DOM objects using Object.prototype.

IE doesn't let you use a prototype that is not native..

You'll have to make a separate function (global if you want) as

```
function isInteger(num) {
  return (num ^ 0) === num;
}

console.log(isInteger(1));
```

Comment: This function works incorrect when integer presented as string. I undertstand that may be it correct for majority cases. But. If your number can be wrapped in quotes, you can use the best answer from here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270648/determine-if-javascript-value-is-an-integer)  `Math.floor(id) == id && $.isNumeric(id)`

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding possible issues with adding to native prototypes in MSIE, your function body is inappropriate for a method added to `Number.prototype`.

Methods on the prototype are called on *instances* of the type, and the instance is passed as `this` (and will always be an object, not a primitive).

Therefore a more correct implementation would be:

```
Number.prototype.isInteger = function() {
  return (this ^ 0) === +this;
}
```

with usage:

```
(1).isInteger();
```

If you wanted to use `Number.isInteger(n)` instead, you would have had to add your function directly to the `Number` object, not its prototype.  There's a rigorous shim for this on [the MDN page for this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and link for Number.isInteger in MDN.But '("1").isInteger();' will throw error:Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Create a polyfill `Number.isInteger`

```
Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
    return typeof value === "number" &&
           isFinite(value) &&
           Math.floor(value) === value;
};
```

This should solve the issue related to IE.