# checking if input is integer using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

that's what I have tried :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
if (Number.isInteger(num)) { 
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Number is integer";
} else {
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Number is not integer";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id = "num"></input>
<button onclick = "myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id = "show">Result Appears Here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem here is that i get "number is not integer" all the time even if the number is integer , the code supposed to check if input is integer or not thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `value` of the `#num` element is returned as a `string` as you can see in the console. Just revert it into a `number` using `+` sign.

Another thing - you are overwriting the `innerHTML` attribute of the `#num` element with every function call. You have to insert the second action `document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Number is not integer"` into the `else` statement to avoid overwriting.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
  console.log(typeof num);

  if (Number.isInteger(+num)) {
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Number is integer";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Number is not integer";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="num"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="show">Result Appears Here</p>
```

There's also another way to check if a number is integer, using `modulo`.

```js
function myFunction(num) {
  num % 1 ? console.log("Not Integer") : console.log("Integer");
}

myFunction(5);
myFunction(5.5);
```

Comment: i totally forgot about that "else" thanks for your help <:

Comment: @AmirWG Check also the second way how to achieve a proper result even quicker. (:

Comment: Note that `"" % 1` and `null % 1` both return `0`, so the modulo method has its quirks.

Comment: @RobG Following your logic - we could put anything else instead of a number - empty object, random string or anything else and probably the output would be improper, but... for what? OP is clearly assuming that the input will be a number. Of course - we could make a condition that if the input isn't typeof number, return false or anything, but does OP actually desires it?

Comment: Where the input is expected to be a string it seems sensible to ensure strings, at least, are integers. A suitable [polyfill for *isInteger*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) is at MDN.

Comment: This is not working in IE. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482645/number-isintegerx-which-is-created-can-not-work-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

Uhm how about try this:

```
if(!isNaN(num)){
    if(Number.isInteger(num){
        //your code
    } else {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother with the *isNaN* test? `Number.isInteger(NaN)` returns false so testing separately for NaN doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit of advice: learn how to properly indent your code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    if (Number.isInteger(num)) { 
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Number is integer";
    }
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Number is not integer";
}
```

If you do, you will easily see that the last line will replace whatever you have put into the paragraph with **Number is not integer**.

You need an `else` to finish the job.

Also, whatever comes out of a text box is a string, so you will have to run it through `parseInt` first.

This might work better:

```
function myFunction() {
    var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value,10);
    if (Number.isInteger(num)) { 
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Number is integer";
    }
    else document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Number is not integer";
}
```

Also:

- `input` is a *void* element, meaning that it doesn’t have a closing tag.
- For HTML attributes, you really shouldn’t have spaces around the `=` sign, as some browsers misinterpret this. For example: `id="something"`