# How can I detect if an input field has an integer number with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, string, validation, input, integer

I have a form with an input text field and I want to validate it before I submit the form.

You can enter a natural number like `1, 5, 7` etc or you can enter a float number like `1.5, 5.45, 7.38`

How can I detect when the input has an Integer (natural) number or not?

If I'm using:

```
typeof($(input[name='myField']).val())
```

I always get it as a string.

I tried to convert the string to a number, but using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` doesn't help, as I convert it directly from the code.

I need to know what type of number is the one in the string from the input field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270648/determine-if-javascript-value-is-an-integer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/du0w8opg/

Comment: @Anant, that might work. Let me test it on my side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304052/check-if-a-number-has-a-decimal-place-is-a-whole-number

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research and based on a few hints/comments on this question, i have fixed it with this simple trick (hope it will help others too).

```
var myInput = $(input[name='myField']).val();
//get the input string value and convert it to float
var myFloatInput = parseFloat(myInput);

if (myFloatInput % 1 != 0) {
//the number is not Integer
}else{
//the number is Integer
}
```

Here are more details about this trick: [Check if a number has a decimal place/is a whole number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304052/check-if-a-number-has-a-decimal-place-is-a-whole-number)

Answer (score -1):

```
 function checkNumber(n) {
      x = `'${n}'`;
     let s = x.indexOf('.');
     if(s == '-1') {
      alert('this natural number');
     }else {
      alert('this float');
     }
  }
  checkNumber(4.5);
```

Also you can use `isInteger` js function

```
Number.isInteger(123);
Number.isInteger(-123);
Number.isInteger('123');
```

Comment: I need to see if it is an Integer (natural number) or a Float, based on the string input.